# Modifying the 'Base' class generated by sqlacodegen

Tags: python, python-3.x, sqlalchemy, sqlacodegen

I want to have a parent class for all of my sqlacodegen classes that map to database tables.

The code generated by sqlacodegen includes the following:

```
Base = declarative_base()
metadata = Base.metadata

class MyFirstClass(Base):
   ....

class MySecondClass(Base):
   ....
```

Base is indeed that parent class. How can I either:
1) Add functionality to Base?
2) Make a parent class for Base so I can add that functionality in there.

Where do I put the common code that all these classes (those mapped to the database tables) share?

Comment: You do need to understand what is the *purpose* of `sqlacodegen` - it is supposed to create the model classes for an *existing* database *once*, after which you'd change the *Python model* and generate migrations using Alembic.

Comment: @AnttiHaapala, OK. I promise I will never run sqlacodegen again after this first time. :) But to add functionality, I still need a way to modify the 'Base' class or extend it from a class I generate that has the functionality. How do I do that?

Comment: http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/extensions/declarative/mixins.html#augmenting-the-base

Comment: @AnttiHaapala. Thanks! that works, although a little confusing that Base seems to be both the name of my base class and the class that inherits from it.  Base = declarative_base(cls=Base)

Comment: You can rename the first instance if you want. I had to check and indeed they do not refer to the same object

Comment: When you figure out, you should make a self-answer then ;-)